# Importing LocalBase library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help with something that is probably really simple, I'll try to be as comprehensive as possible. I am trying to use a lib called `LocalBase` https://github.com/dannyconnell/localbase as a simple database for my static web, it's a simplified version of IndexDB. So my coding experience will be streamlined and just seems too simple.

I have a `main.js` file that I want to use for scripts so I don't clutter my `.HTML` file with js script

How do I import it so I can use it?

I installed Node.JS and I thought about simply just doing `npm localbase --save` and (this is from the localbase git readme)

```js
import Localbase from 'localbase'

let db = new Localbase('db')
```

and I would go from there...

But I would always get some errors like these:

- https://gyazo.com/e20c5f3a3aff3f1ff673ed587baa44ac
- https://gyazo.com/364f6a82676c7d94f19cf091cfbd2607

I've even tried script tags, but now I would get errors like:

- https://gyazo.com/ee6b59d6a0d5455e7485c27f27131331

I'm a real beginner at this stuff and I am wondering how this is done and in a very easy manner, this is for a school project.

My current code: https://jsfiddle.net/ko58Lf34/

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we could see your code. There is probably something you are doing wrong.

According to the [Localbase](https://github.com/dannyconnell/localbase#installation--initialisation) documentation, a declaration in the script tag of a .html file should be enough.

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/localbase/dist/localbase.dev.js"></script>

<script>
  let db = new Localbase('db')
</script>
```